# How to access pipe results in Angular to use in a different element?

Tags: angular

I am trying to show "   No items to display " to display on search.But it not working.I am not able to find out the array object length. So, Hos to find it. If anyone knows please help with the solution.
Please check my demo for more.

```
<div *ngIf="!__allprdts">
      No items to display
</div>
```

For Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-sxkdrh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fproductslist.dir.ts

Comment: for objects, you can use `Object.values(yourObject).length` and for arrays `yourArray.length`

Comment: @RameshReddy: Can you update your code on my stackblitz?

Comment: @RameshReddy: Not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-j44nx2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fproductslist.dir.ts

Comment: that's because the filtering is handled by angular so the array's length never changes

Comment: @RameshReddy: So, Is it not possible?

Comment: It is possible by using the result of the pipe, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the result of the piped array in a variable that's scoped to `ng-container` and use its length to conditionally display the message:

Here's the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-nemtan?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fproductslist.dir.ts)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(__allprdts
          | filter: __searchedProduct
          | sortBy: sortByOption
          | paginate: config) as result">
```

the filtered, sorted, paginated array will be stored as `result`

Now you can use `result`'s length

```
<div *ngIf="result.length === 0">
 No items to display
</div>
```

Comment: Can you apply the result length to pagination totalitems: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-fasnuv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fproductslist.dir.ts

Comment: @Sansara Yes you can see this [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-ko5gu8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fproductslist.dir.ts). Make sure that you're using result within ng-container because of scope

Comment: How to assign that length to pagination totalitems? is it possible?

Comment: are you referring to maxSize? I assigned the length to maxSize in the fork

Comment: But Pagination length is not working properly..click the first button then click the third button and check the pagination..not updated the length..i think need to trigger pagination..If i use this.config inside the ngonchanges it is working..but i do not know that is proper method or not. please tell me.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-qrqbfq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fproductslist.dir.ts